# Python qiskit metal window is not responding

Tags: python, qiskit

I am just a beginner today installed qiskit metal and tried to run the very first code. But when the window with qiskit metal opened up, I wasn't able to click anything. Every time I tried to click something, it displayed to me, that the window is no longer responding and I wasn't able to use it whatsoever. Have you got any suggestions on what might cause this error?
Thanks in advance

Here is my code in Python VSC:

```py
from qiskit_metal import designs, draw, MetalGUI, Dict, open_docs
design = designs.DesignPlanar()
design.overwrite_enabled = True
design.chips.main
design.chips.main.size.size_x = '11mm'
design.chips.main.size.size_y = '9mm'
gui = MetalGUI(design)

from qiskit_metal.qlibrary.qubits.transmon_pocket import TransmonPocket
q1 = TransmonPocket(design, 'Q1', options=dict(connection_pads=dict(a=dict())))
gui.rebuild()
gui.edit_component('Q1')
gui.autoscale()

q1.options.pos_x = '0.5 mm'
q1.options.pos_y = '0.25 mm'
q1.options.pad_height = '90um'
q1.options.pad_width  = '455um'
q1.options.pad_gap    = '30 um'

input()  # for no closing the window
```